# F# - Associating a function with the matching type of object

Tags: design, functional-programming, f#, pattern-matching

Let's say I'm programming a chess game. At some point I have to check, which moves are valid for a given piece. What would be the proper way to select the correct pathfinding function for a given piece (king, queen, etc.)?

I came up with three different approaches:

1. Store the pathfinding method (alongside the other data) inside a record (similar to the strategy pattern; *too* object oriented?)
2. Create a `PieceType` Discriminated Union with all piece types and store a value of this type in the record. Select the proper pathfinding function via pattern matching
3. Create a `PieceData` record-type which stores the data and a `Piece` DU, where all cases represent different piece types and are of type `PieceData`. Pattern matching is also used to select the correct function.

Here is some sample code, demonstrating the different approaches:

```
// The piece "constructor" is private as to only allow creating pieces via
// the provided construct functions for each piece type
type Piece = private { Position:Position; Pathfinder:Position->Board->Position list }

let kingPathfinder position board =
    // Check and return all possible targets for a king

let createKing position =
    { Position=position; Pathfinder=kingPathfinder }

let getPossibleTargets { Position=position; Pathfinder=pathfinder } board =
    pathfinder position board


    ####    ####    ####


type PieceType =
    | King
    | ...

type Piece = { Position:Position; PieceType:PieceType }

let kingPathfinder position board =
    // Check and return all possible targets for a king

let createKing position =
    { Position=position; PieceType=King }

let getPossibleTargets { Position=position; PieceType=pieceType } board =
    match pieceType with
        | King -> kingPathfinder position board
        | ...


    ####    ####    ####


type PieceData = { Position:Position }

type Piece =
    | King of PieceData
    | ...

let kingPathfinder position board =
    // Check and return all possible targets for a king

let createKing position =
    King { Position=position }

let getPossibleTargets piece board =
    match piece with
        | King { Position:position } ->
            kingPathfinder position board
```

My question now is: Which one of these three approaches is preferred in functional programming? Or is there another, superior way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second approach is the best.

First approach admits invalid data - i.e. you can put any function in place of `PawnData.Pathfinder`, and there is no way to enforce that it's a valid one.

Third approach is generally ok, but in this specific case it's a little wasteful, because all cases of the DU have identical data.

Second approach is the right one for this particular problem.

Also, you're confusing terms a bit. The word "pawn" means [a specific type of chess piece](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawn_(chess)) - the one of which there are eight. Saying "pawn of type King" is kind of like saying "bishop of type King". The correct term for this is "piece":

```
type PieceType =
   | King
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question for clarity. I also modified my first approach, so it's clear, that I only want to create pieces via the provided construct functions. So I don't think invalid data is possible? Still, I also think the second one is the most natural and the third one a tad "wasteful".

Comment: Even though you made the constructor private, the type itself still doesn't constrain the data. The correctness of `getPossibleTargets` now depends on the correctness of some other code (i.e. `createKing`) that is located in a different place. Private constructor is a good strategy when you don't have any other way to guarantee data correctness (i.e. "last resort"). But in this case you do.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you mean, thanks for clarifying. Just out of curiosity: Is it then usually "bad", to have a function as a record field or are there valid use cases for them?

Comment: Yes, there are valid cases. One that immediately comes to mind is passing an "options" record  to a function - a common way to get around the "too many parameters" problem. In general, valid cases for "function in record" are same as valid cases for "function as parameter".